# Why doesn't this 2D collision fully work for my images?

Tags: javascript, 2d, collision

I am having a collision in my javascipt game among the player, bullets, and enemies. Previously, the bullets have been rectangles, but I now have images. The images fit tightly into a rectangular box, the 2D collision was expected to work. Here is the image: 
[image: Bullet]

The bullet is somewhat rectangular. I use this logic in my collision system:

```
    return rect1.x <= rect2.x+rect2.width
    && rect2.x<=rect1.x+rect1.width
    && rect1.y<=rect2.y+rect2.height//if all statements are true, they are     colliding
    && rect2.y<=rect1.y+rect1.height;
```

Collision somewhat works, however, the bullet can be significantly below the player and still trigger the collision and it can be significantly a third way inside the player from the top without triggering the collision. Is there anything I can do to fix it? The collision system worked flawlessly with just rectangles and should be close enough here, but it is not good enough. Here is the link to my actual game in development if you want to see the source code and the issue for yourself: 
[JS Game](http://solonkojsgame.net16.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove your equals signs and do not check for collision but for being "outside".

```
if (rect1.x + rect1.width < rect2.x) //left outside
   return false;
if (rect1.x > rect2.x + rect2.width) //right outside
   return false;
if (rect1.y + rect1.height < rect2.y) //above/below outside
   return false;
if (rect1.y > rect2.y + rect2.height) //above/below outside
   return false;
return true;
```

(You could also wrap them into one line, but I hope this makes clear what I want to say) Does this example work different for your game?

Comment: I tried using your code and the result was the same. This works with rectangles, but for some reason, it is shifted with the image. I tried playing around with the values. If rect1y<rect2y+rect2height-10. It shifts the collision in the preferred direction. I still, however, don't understand why this issue is there.

Comment: Then it seems that your issue may be rather in the placement of your images, than with your collision detection. How do you embed your image into your (invisible) rectangle?

Comment: You are right, it was a placement issue. The images top left corner was at its x and y, however in the collision, it was made for those coordinates to be in the center. I did this now: drawImage(img, x-width/2, y-height/2, width, height). Thank you